Need the name of this 80s Vampire TV series episode/short movie?
Definitely not big budget. Production values felt like Dark Shadows of the 1990s.  One of the soon-to-be-revealed vampires is a middle-aged caucasian woman. The episode/mini-movie started out with the still-alive victims complaining that the mysterious bite marks on their bodies were probably nettle stings?  The only other scene I remember vividly is that the above woman gets hit by a car and presumed for dead, only to return on one of her nightly feeding visits dressed in a white.
Update: 
More recollections: Based in a open spaces/countryside setting, not an urban city. English or American ... not sure?

I think you may mean Mrs Amworth, a 1975 British short based on an E. F. Benson short story (no nettles, that I recall, but other details check out). On youtube here: MRS AMWORTH

Perfect!  This was the one.

Watched it again. I was a bit young so I misheard gnats for nettles as it turns out.

It wasn't just vampires, but I wonder if this is the program you are looking for.
Kolchak: The Night Stalker
While it was slightly earlier than the eighties it was repeated, so could well have been seen for the first time in the eighties.

Can you specify why you think it's this show and which episode is the OP looking for?

Specifically I think he may be remembering episode 4 which involved a female vampire who is unearthed by a road construction crew, gets hit by a car and then returns later.  Can't recall if there was a white dress though, it's been a while.

@Chris Harland: Your answer seemed promising but after reading the episode review on a Kolchak wiki, I'm afraid that wasn't it.  The one I am trying to remember was not based in Vegas/Los Angeles but based in more of a english/American outdoor countryside (hence the nettles) setting.

That was an awesome show, regardless of whether it was the correct answer.
